# pandas dataframe inserting null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
index  a     b      c     d
1      x     x      x     x 
2      x     nan    x     x
3      x     x      x     x
4      x     nan    x     x


index  a     b        e
3      x     nan      x 
4      x     x        x
5      x     nan      x
6      x     x        x
```

I want to make it into the following, where we simply get rid of the NaN values.  An easier version of this question is where the second dataframe has no nan values....

```
index  a    b    c    d   e
1      x    x    x    x   x
2      x    x    x    x   x
3      x    x    x    x   x
4      x    x    x    x   x
5      x    x    x    x   x
6      x    x    x    x   x
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `combine_first` with `fillna`:

> DataFrame.**combine_first**(*other*)
>
> Combine two DataFrame objects and
>   default to non-null values in frame calling the method. Result index
>   columns will be the union of the respective indexes and columns

You can read the doc from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[nan,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]], columns=['a','b','c'])

d1
    a  b  c
0 NaN  1  1
1   2  2  2
2   3  3  3

d2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,nan,1],[nan,2,2],[3,3,nan]], columns=['b','d','e'])

d2
    b   d   e
0   1 NaN   1
1 NaN   2   2
2   3   3 NaN
```

---

```
d2.combine_first(d1) # d1's values are prioritized, if d2 has no NaN
    a  b  c   d   e
0 NaN  1  1 NaN   1
1   2  2  2   2   2
2   3  3  3   3 NaN

d2.combine_first(d1).fillna(5) # simply fill NaN with a value
   a  b  c  d  e
0  5  1  1  5  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nan_to_num` to replace a nan with a number:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html

Just apply this:

```
from numpy import nan_to_num
df2 = df.apply(nan_to_num)
```

Then you can merge the arrays however you want.

Comment: So I believe this solution should work, but I'm getting a strange type error for the test dataset that I chose.  Does it work for you?

Also, try `nan_to_num(df)`

Comment: see above solution for .fillna example. another way to do this is to interpolate.  another command in the later version of pandas.

Comment: Ya, fillNA is a better way to go.